# bootstrap progress bar style for width is not working with angular js bound variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Progress Bar width is not getting updated by the variable bound by angular scope in IE.

I want to have a progress bar length to be updated by a variable in angular scope, for that i have tried using the angular expression directly in the in-line style element and also tried with ng-style attribute.

Its working properly in Firefox and Chrome, while on IE its failing to set the width of the progress bar.

Inspect element of the "div" element in IE shows as below

```
Inline Style { width : {{value}}% }
```

My understanding here, is the expression is not getting evaluated in the style attribute in Internet Explorer.

You can find the complete test script in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaths/7h5fx/10/)

Just wondering have anyone faced the same issue, anytime when working with the combination of bootstrap with angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ng-style

http://jsfiddle.net/un8B5/

html:

```
ng-style="myStyle"
```

js:

```
$scope.myStyle = {width: $scope.value + '%'};
```

Comment: Thanks alot it did work, I did ```ng-style={width:$scope.value+'%'}``` earler, and it didn't work. Your solution to have a binding variable for style is working. And there was a small issue with your fiddle as the progress bar width is not altering based on the input, which i corrected [here in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaths/Gp97t/)

Comment: Updated jsfiddle again to only change the width of the style (so you can apply other styles to the same var if you want).

:)

http://jsfiddle.net/bPf8n/

$scope.myStyle.width = $scope.value + '%';

Answer (score 2):

To add on for IE, you may need to use ng-attr-style to get it to properly update the progress bar width.

The problem is that some browsers like IE do not play nice when trying to bind attributes and using this lets you get around.

This is what mine ended up looking like: `ng-attr-style="width:{{vm.uploadProgressPercent}}%"`

Hope this helps somebody!

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes